# Dynamic Selectors with Jquery with php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, click

I have a while loop which creates a list of anchor tags each with a unique class name counting from 1 to however many items there are. I would like to change a css attriubute on a specific anchor tag and class when it is clicked so lets say the background color is changed. Here is my code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
 $title = $row['title'];
 $i++;
 echo "<a class='$i'>$title</a>

}
```

I would like my jquery to look something like this, it is obviously going to be more complicated than this I am just confused as where to start.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a .1 .2 .3 .4 and so on').click(function() {
$('a ./*whichever class was clicked*/').css('background':'red');
        });
   });
```

Comment: Instead of "unique" classes, I would use IDs. And it seems that the same action is performed regardless which of the links was clicked, so why not just give them a common class. This is what are classes for, assign similar behaviour/properties so multiple elements.

Comment: One other error I just noticed (and corrected in my answer) is that you have a `:` as the separator in your `.css()` call instead of a `,`. The colon is used only if your passing an object to `.css()`.

Comment: I agree with @Felix. Unless you have a specific purpose for the class names as numbers (like if you will have other elements with the same class name), IDs are typically used as unique identifiers (though a single number as an ID is not valid), and the classes could be identical. The index number could also be passed in a custom attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give the class a more consistent name? Like `myClass_1`, `myClass_2`, etc.

Then you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[class^=myClass_]').click(function() { // Assign handler to elements with a
                                               //  class that starts with 'myClass_'
        $(this).css('background','red');  // Change background of clicked one.

    });
});
```

Here, a "starts with" selector is used to assign the event to all classes that start with `myClass`.

You could still retrieve the index number if needed.

Within the event handler, `$(this)` refers to the one that was clicked.

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jurv3/

**Docs for "starts with" selector:** http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

**EDIT:** I had a missing `]` in the selector. Fixed now.

Comment: There's no reason to give each a unique class if you're referring to $(this)

Comment: @colinmarc - The OP is using unique classes for some reason, therefore my answer reflects the requirement of the OP. There could be other sets of elements being generated with identical class names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iterator over an array like this:

```
var myclasses = [".1",".2",".3"]; // generated by php

$.each(myclasses, function(index, value) { 
    $('a '+value).click(function() {
        $(this).css('background':'red');
    });
});
```

**Note:** I think you might be better off using unique ID for each item in your list of anchor tags and have them all share a single class. That's more what classes and IDs are for.

Answer (score 1):

Just give them all the same class, say, `myClass`. Then:

```
$('a.myClass').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background':'red');
});
```

This will work as long as you're having the links operate on themselves, or on their parents - as long as the relationship between link and target is the same for each. To operate on the parent, it would be `$(this).parent().css(...)`, and to operate on the next element it would be `$(this).next().css(...)` and so on.

Comment: You don't need to use `each()` to assign the handlers to all the `myClass` elements.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
 $title = $row['title'];
 $i++;
 echo '<a class="anchor_link" id="'.$i.'">'.$title.'</a>';

}
```

And then for the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.anchor_link').click(function() {
        var thisAnchor = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css('background':'red');
    });
});
```

The reason for my adding the js var 'thisAnchor' is because I am assuming that you need that $i php variable as the anchor marker?  if so you can just take the js var and use it however you need.  if you can't use ID because the anchored content is marked by id, use a diferent attr, such as 'title' or 'alt'.

I hope this was helpful.